# String Array Into HashMap Collection Object

Tags: java, hashmap, arrays

I have the following

```
 String[] temp;
```

which returns

```
red
blue
green
```

I would like to add the string array into a collection obejct like HashMap so that I could retrieve values in any class like

```
HashMap hash = New HashMap();
hash.get("red");
hash.get("blue");
hash.get("green");
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Update 1

```
     String str = "red,blue,green";
        String[] temp;
        String delimiter = ",";
        temp = str.split(delimiter);
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
System.out.println(temp[i]);
}
```

With the above code, I would like to retrieve values based on values in array. E.g. I would like to get the values in from another class by calling hash.get("One"), which would return red, hash.get("Two") which would return blue and so forth.

Comment: create map using Map hash = New HashMap<String, String>();
Then hash.put("red", "red"), .... will work

Comment: What would be the "values" that you expect to retrieve ?

Comment: If you create a new Hashmap, it will be empty in the beginning. And what do you want to get from the hashmap? The string 'red'? If you have it already - why do you need a HashMap?

Comment: What values do you want to associate with each String? Unless you need values associated you can use a List<String> or Set<String>

Comment: I am retrieving array values like the following `for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) { System.out.println(temp[i]); }`. My doubt how I do map temp[i] with red, blue or green?

Comment: What is the goal of whatever you are trying to do. Please be more specific or post the code that you have right now and we can try to change it.

Comment: I have added my code as Update 1

Comment: "One", "Two" as strings? Or 1, 2 as numbers? And why would you need strings?

Comment: Even number is fine, no need to have strings. Yes number I put as key value in HashMap and that solved. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Map<String, String> hash = new HashMap<String, String>();    
for(i = 0 ; i < temp.length(); i++)
{
   hash.put(temp[i], temp[i]);
}
```

Then you can retrieve from map 
hash.get (temp[i]);

Comment: I tried your solution. I have a question, could it be possible to be make more generic i.e. if I calling hash.get from another class I wouldn't be able to call with temp[i].

Comment: Yes, you can call from another class, if your hash is public field. But to get the values in the hash you need to know the Key.So what i mean to say whether you call from same class or another class, you need to know the key, probably you do like hash.get("red") , where red you get as an input in another class.

Comment: I resolved the issue of key value with an integer and iterating integer value inside loop when I am adding values to HashMap. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
HashMap<String, String>() map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put(temp[i], temp[i]);//here i have considered key as the value itself.. u can use something else //also.
```

Answer (score -1):

> My doubt how I do map temp[i] with red, blue or green?

Using a hash map won't solve this problem directly. Currently you need to write

```
 temp[ someNumberHere ];
```

so

```
 temp[ 1 ];
```

yields a String "blue"

If you have a hashMap then instead you might write

```
 myColourMap.get( someNumberHere );
```

so

```
 myColourMap.get( 1 );
```

Would yield "blue". In either case you are converting a value to a corresponding string, but you do need to know that "someNumber". If you want "blue" you need to know to ask for number 1.

It may be that what you need is to use nicely named constant values:

```
public Class Colours {

     public static final int RED = 0;
     public static final int BLUE = 1;
     public static final int GREEN = 1; 

     // plus either the array of strings or the hashMap

     public statuc String getColour(int colourNumber ) {
           return myArray[colourNumber]; // or myMap.get(colourNumber)
     }

}
```

Your clients can now write code such as

```
 Colours.getColour( Colour.RED );
```

[It is better to use enums than just raw ints, but let's not divert from arrays and hashMaps right now].

Now when might you prefer a hashMap  instead of an array? Consider that you might have more colours, for example 12695295 might be "light pink" and 16443110 might be "lavender".

Now you really don't want an array with 16,443,110 entries when you are only using perhaps 500 of them. Now a HashMap is a really useful thing

```
 myMap.put( Colour.LAVENDER, 16443110 );
```

and so on.